# Can anyone explain this weird behaviour of MariaDB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am creating a blog with basic functionalities , one of them is adding posts to the database.

Here is the code that I had written which inserts data into database when user clicks submit :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      //Assign the variables
      $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['title']);
      $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['category']);
      $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['body']);
      $author = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['author']);
      $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['tags']);

      // //Simlpe Validation
      if($title == '' || $category='' ||$body == '' || $author == ''){
        //Set Error
        $error = 'Please fill out all the required fields.';
      } 
      else{
      $query = "insert into posts (title, body, author, tags, category) values ('$title','$body', '$author', '$tags',$category)";

        $insert_row = $db->insert($query);
      }
    }
```

The error says :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

And here comes the weird part.

When I exclude the if and else statements and directly run the query outside if and else statements like this :

```
  $query = "insert into posts (title, body, author, tags, category) values ('$title','$body', '$author', '$tags',$category)";

  $insert_row = $db->insert($query);

  // Simlpe Validation
  // if($title == '' || $category='' ||$body == '' || $author == ''){
  //   //Set Error
  //   $error = 'Please fill out all the required fields.';
  // } 
  // else{

  // }
```

But using the above code the query runs perfectly and database gets updated.

Can anyone explain this?

I am having a hard time to understand why it is behaving this way.

By the way, here is the method in the Database class for insert :

```
/*
*   Insert
*/

        public function insert($query){

            $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error);

            //Validate insert
            if($insert_row){
                header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
                exit();
            }
            else{
                die('Error: ('.$this->link->errno.') '.$this->link->error);
            }
        }
```

**Edit** :
Some people asked about 'category'. Well, $_POST['category'] is an integer and the column category of the posts table is also an integer, obviously. That is why I didn't keep any quotations around $category in the query.

Comment: To begin with, please add logging of the string being sent towards MySQL in both scenarios. According to the error message, there is a syntactic error in the string, so we better start analyzing that specific element before digging into your code.

Comment: I ran the same query on phpmyadmin, and there was no error, the query executed perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I understood that from your post. Still, add logging in both scenarios and post it.

Comment: What's the value of `$category`?

Comment: @Barmar value of category is an integer. It stores the category number.

Comment: @FDavidov when you said 'add logging in both scenarios' What do you mean by that? I am an amateur. :|

Comment: Amateur: We all were at some point. Logging: I mean print on screen the **exact** string being sent towards the database server. See? It is enough to have an extra comma or whatever character to make the statement illegal.

Comment: @madhuspot What he means is `echo $query;`.

Comment: @FDavidov I did what you had suggested. And I came across another weird thing. If the first case, when the query is under if/else statement, the value of the category is nil. And out side the if/else statement the value of category is displayed. And I guess I finally understood what was wrong with the code. I made a blunder in if statement where in I put $constant='', I missed the extra '=', so basically it overwrote the value of $constant producing a extra comma.

Comment: See how logging helps during the debugging process? It is a good, very common and highly helpful practice.

Comment: How does "News" get turned into an integer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @FDavidov for suggesting me to start logging in both the scenarios. And I found that in if statement, instead of this:

```
$constant == ''
```

I wrote this :

```
$constant =''
```

[image]

Which overwrote the value of `$category`, therefore by this there was a leading `,`(extra comma) in the query which resulted in syntactical error.

I corrected it back to `$constant == ''`. Now everything is fine.